# TypeError: string indices must be integers when trying to parse api response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, python-requests

I'm trying to take an API response and store name data under "name" in a python list. When I do this, I seem to get this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. Can I possibly get some help on fixing this?

Example API Response:

```
[{'name': 'cocoachihuahua'}, {'name': 'Knavish', 'changedToAt': 1487739619000}, {'name': 'Tahmara', 'changedToAt': 1538013607000}, {'name': 'KnavishSavage', 'changedToAt': 1541349612000}, {'name': 'Tareyy', 'changedToAt': 1543953561000}, {'name': 'asagod', 'changedToAt': 1548964110000}, {'name': 'cyfry', 'changedToAt': 1553359528000}, {'name': 'asagod', 'changedToAt': 1554188609000}, {'name': 'KnavishSavage', 'changedToAt': 1560524856000}, {'name': 'YG0', 'changedToAt': 1566545250000}, {'name': 'MaryIsAmazing69', 'changedToAt': 1571421602000}, {'name': 'ScuffedWater', 'changedToAt': 1580026242000}, {'name': 'ToggleHUD', 'changedToAt': 1582861414000}, {'name': 'Hauntar', 'changedToAt': 1586331807000}]
```

Code:

```
import requests
import json

target = input()

x = requests.get('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/'+target)
x_data = x.json()

uuid = x_data['id']

y = requests.get('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/'+uuid+'/names')
y_data = y.json()

data = json.dumps(y_data)
usernames = data['name']
```

Comment: You're converting your data that already been parsed from a string to a Python object back to a string: `data = json.dumps(y_data)`

Comment: ok but when I try to do this `usernames = y_data['name']` I get another error

Comment: y_data is a list not a dictionary?

Comment: yes and how do I take names from y_data then?

Comment: `usernames = [x['name'] for x in y_data]`